# Simple jQuery GET request

Tags: php, jquery, get

I am trying to have a onclick button call send a get request to a php file.
The jQuery is loading properly so that is not the problem.

Here is the code:

**The function to be called**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function deleteLecturer(email){
         $.get("http://localhost/AMS/lecturers.php",
            {
                to_delete: email 
            }, 
            function(data, textStatus){
                alert(textStatus);
            });
    };
        </script>
```

**The button:**

```
<a href='' onclick="deleteLecturer('{$lecturers[1][$i]}')">Delete</a>
```

and the php file has the following if check:

```
if (isset($_GET['to_delete'])){
      $email = $_GET['to_delete'];
      $deletelecturer="DELETE FROM `lecturers` WHERE lect_email='$email';";
      return true;
  }
```

However it is not working.. Any thoughts?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: do you see any errors..?

Comment: shouldn't this --> {$lecturers[1][$i]} be in php tags like onclick="<?php echo $lecturers[1][$i]; ?>" ... ..?

Comment: no errors. The {$lecturers[1][$i]} is currect since I am using smarty template.

Comment: Please show the generated HTML, not the template. Have you confirmed that the URL the browser calls is correct (look in the browser dev tools)? If you type the URL in the browser directly, does it work, i.e. is it a problem with the JavaScript or the PHP code?

Comment: And in fact, is that the whole PHP code? Because what you have shown doesn't do anything.

Comment: Look below for the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always had rotten experiences with browsers when the `href` attribute is an empty string (e.g., `onclick` won't fire). Set the `href` to `#` and then `return false` in your function to prevent the `#` from appearing at the end of your URL in the address bar.

Also, I'm pretty sure that Sudhir is correct. Your `'{$lecturers[1][$i]}'` parameter should be wrapped in PHP tags.

```
<a href='#' onclick="deleteLecturer('<?php {$lecturers[1][$i]}; ?>')">Delete</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteLecturer(email){
        $.get("http://localhost/AMS/lecturers.php", {
            to_delete: email 
        }, function(data, textStatus){
            alert(textStatus);
        });
        return false; //prevents the navigation to url#
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Boom that was it! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (`to_delete` in quotes)

```
script type='text/javascript'>

    function deleteLecturer(email){
         $.get("http://localhost/AMS/lecturers.php",
            {
                "to_delete": email 
            }, 
            function(data, textStatus){
                alert(textStatus);
            });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: quotes are not necessary...though a good practice..

Comment: I know, it is just a suggestion. ;)

Answer (score -4):

Do you have the following in your code (but not your example above)?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   // your code here
});
</script>
```

If you do not have this wrapped around your jquery script then it won't fire. You won't get an error, but nothing will happen all the same.

Comment: can't you see this big thing : `onclick="deleteLecturer('{$lecturers[1][$i]}')"`

Comment: Damn, I whiffed right over that. No more pre-coffee answers for me!